# I cant monitor my fan speed on my HP Pavilion Gaming laptop 15

Tags: laptop, fan, hp-pavilion, sensors

Device Specification:

Device name-    LAPTOP-B9SLVP96

Processor-  AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics 3.00 GHz

Installed RAM-  8.00 GB (7.36 GB usable)

Device ID-  E6C61B4D-41D3-4FFE-B347-661A3A8E1754

Product ID- 00327-36285-79753-AAOEM

[HWINFO showing no fan details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jr6fX.png)

[MSI Afterburn showing no fan details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyZxo.png)

Comment: If the fan does not have the outputs for  The WMI command-line (WMIC)  then you cannot get the speed. That is so for numerous computers.

Comment: so I could never monitor fan speed 

Comment: That is correct. If the fan does not have the outputs then you cannot monitor.